# How do I add custom code to WordPress that I can then edit daily without having to change the code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, codepen

I'm currently learning web dev and some HTML/CSS by creating my own website via WordPress and struggling to understand how you can input coded templates that you can then edit through Elementor/customiser without having to change the code each time.

Just for an example, if I wanted to insert the following https://codepen.io/havardob/pen/MWKWZxZ to my WordPress site (which I have done), is there a way to edit the content without having to go in and change the code each time, e.g. the team names? Or if I created my own blog style containers/templates in VSCode and put them into WordPress, is there a way to write content in them in the same way I would if it was a WordPress template (not having to write in the `<p> </p>` lines of code each time)?

Hopefully that makes sense what I'm trying to ask, sorry if it doesn't I'm still learning!

Thanks very much.

I've inputted the Codepen code into my website just as a test and then realised there's no way to edit.

Comment: The  Code Snippets plugin may help.